# How to add multiple cards in same customer in stripe payment gateway using php

Tags: php, stripe-payments

i was implementing stripe payment in testing mode.Here i got an error like Same token is used again. is there any different way to add multiple cards.
or i need to call retrive function in a separate page so that conflict of same token never come again.And how should i set a card default.

```
public function createToken($data)
{

        $TokenResult=Token::create(array(
            "card" => array(
            "name" => $data['name'],
            "number" => $data['card_number'],
            "exp_month" => $data['month'],
            "exp_year" => $data['year'],
            "cvc" => $data['cvc']
            )));
        //echo "<pre>";;
        //print_r($TokenResult);
        $this->token=$TokenResult['id'];//store token id into token variable
        $this->chargeCard($this->token);    //call chargecard function via passing token id
}
/*
* function to create customer
*/
public function createCustomer($data,$token=null)//pass form data and token id
{
    $customer=Customer::create(array(
    "email"=>$data['email'],
    "description" => $data['name'],
    "source" => $token // obtained with Stripe.js
    ));
    $customerId=$customer['id'];
    $this->retriveCustomer($customerId,$token);
}
/*
* function to retrive current customers for adding multiple cards to same customers*/
public function retriveCustomer($customerid,$token)
{
    echo $this->token;
    //die('here');
    $retriveResult=Customer::retrieve($customerid);
    $retriveResult->sources->create(array("source" =>$this->token));
    return $retriveResult;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, please note that unless you are PCI certified and allowed to directly manipulate card data, you should never have access to card numbers in your server-side code.

Card tokens should be created client-side, via [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) or [Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/elements). Your server should only deal with client-side created card tokens and never with PCI-sensitive information (card numbers and CVCs). This will greatly decrease the burden of PCI compliance and make you eligible for [PCI SAQ A](https://stripe.com/docs/security#pci-dss-guidelines).

In PHP, this is how you'd [add a card](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_card) to an existing customer object:

```
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve("cus_...");
$card = $customer->sources->create(array(
    "source" => $token  // token created by Checkout or Elements
));
```

Comment: $customer = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve("cus_...");
$card = $customer->sources->create(array(
    "source" => $token  // token created by Checkout or Elements
));  this will add same card again...

Comment: It's up to you to check that the card is already attached to the customer. You can do this by using the token ID to retrieve the full token object (https://stripe.com/docs/api#retrieve_token) and compare the token's `card.fingerprint` attribute to the `fingerprint` of cards that are already attached to the customer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont need to create a token in case of adding new card. It helps while you update certain card. So the flow of addition will be same as you created for first card.

I dont know which stripe version you are using, I am using bit old:

```
$card_array = array(
               'card' => array(
               'number' => $number,
               'exp_month' => $exp_month,
               'exp_year' => $exp_year,
               'cvc' => $cvc,
               'name' => $name
               )
           );


$card_obj = $this->setData("\Stripe\Customer", "retrieve", $customer_id, TRUE);
$card =  $card_obj->sources->create($card_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Stripe's docs don't explain a lot of the more nuanced procedures so you have to do a lot of testing.

Assuming you have a customer object $cu, with the token you get from checkout or whatever you use:

```
$card = $cu->sources->create(['source'=>$token]);
```

will add a card to the customer. It just adds the card to the list; subsequent calls will add cards to the list. Note that it does not check for duplicates, so the same card can be on the list multiple times. It will also not set the new card to the active card. To make a card the default (or active), use

```
$cu->default_source = $card
$cu->save();
```

Using the older card interface:

```
$cu->card = $token;
$cu->save();
```

The new card will replace the default card. It will NOT make the previously default card inactive; it will delete the current default and make the new card the active default. The card interface is the easiest if you're just allowing 1 card to be attached to a customer at a time.